# How to search column values for date and replace with today's date in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the excel file with a column name is "Pickup Time" with different date and timing (may be in string or date format)

```
13/Jan/2019 10:00:00 PM
17/Jan/2019 06:01:00 AM
16/Jan/2019 08:00:00 PM
17/Jan/2019 04:01:00 AM
15/Jan/2019 06:00:00 AM
16/Jan/2019 02:01:00 PM
16/Jan/2019 09:00:00 PM
17/Jan/2019 05:01:00 AM
16/Jan/2019 04:00:00 PM
17/Jan/2019 12:01:00 AM
16/Jan/2019 05:00:00 PM
17/Jan/2019 01:01:00 AM
16/Jan/2019 07:30:00 PM
14/Jan/2019 03:31:00 AM
16/Jan/2019 08:20:00 PM
17/Jan/2019 04:21:00 AM
11/Jan/2019 10:00:00 PM
```

Now I want to only replace the dates in that column with today's date and keep the timing, how could I get that done ? The expected result will look like this:

```
17/Jan/2019 10:00:00 PM
17/Jan/2019 06:01:00 AM
17/Jan/2019 08:00:00 PM
17/Jan/2019 04:01:00 AM
17/Jan/2019 06:00:00 AM
17/Jan/2019 02:01:00 PM
17/Jan/2019 09:00:00 PM
17/Jan/2019 05:01:00 AM
17/Jan/2019 04:00:00 PM
17/Jan/2019 12:01:00 AM
17/Jan/2019 05:00:00 PM
17/Jan/2019 01:01:00 AM
17/Jan/2019 07:30:00 PM
17/Jan/2019 03:31:00 AM
17/Jan/2019 08:20:00 PM
17/Jan/2019 04:21:00 AM
17/Jan/2019 10:00:00 PM
```

Have looking into lookup and vlookup but seems not to serve this purpose.
Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

```
=TODAY() + TIME(HOUR(A1),MINUTE(A1),SECOND(A1))
```

Comment: so you have to put on another column then drag the format down and copy paste the values ? Can we have a button some where that we click and get all values on that column changed ?

Comment: You can learn how to use Macro. It can record what you do and repeat it by clicking a button.

Comment: how to write that macro , can you give an example please ?

Comment: `=A1-INT(A1)+TODAY()` or `=TODAY()+MOD(A1;1)` work too

Comment: @Joubarc : the first one is not returning the date time but a strange number (e.g. 43483,91667), the second one is work except that you need to uses comma instead, like: =TODAY()+MOD(A1,1). Tks, good to know more !

Comment: @user1314404 a date/time's underlying value is a number. That's the "strange number". Apply a date/time number format to it.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub changeDates()

    Dim cel As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cellTime As Variant

    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & Sheet1.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)

    For Each cel In rng.Cells

        cellTime = Format(TimeValue(cel), "hh:mm")
        cel.Value = Format(Date, "d/mmm/yyyy") + " " + cellTime

    Next cel

End Sub
```

Comment: I changed Set rng to my table range:Set rng = Sheet1.Range("F2:F" & Sheet1.Range("F2").End(xlDown).Row) then I got run time error and click debug it points at this line: cellTime = Format(TimeValue(cel), "hh:mm"). Please refer to my screenshot uploaded on ufile on the below comment.

Comment: not really understand about how to set that range, my purpose is to search all that column cells (the first cell should be column name though). I have tried to change: Dim cellTime as Date then there is no error on that line but next line: cel.Value= Format(Date, ..... but cannot change Dim cel As Date because to use in loop it need to be an object

Comment: Looks like I can fix that error by adding error handling: Dim obj As Object
    Set obj = Application.Selection
    If TypeName(obj) <> "Range" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim cel As Range
    Set cel = obj; however the code run but never update the value. I also do not see anywhere in your code update the date to today's date ?

Comment: I put my answer above which is the code I changed base on your answer then got no error executing it, however, no values are changed or updated. Can figure out why ?

Comment: And I find out your range selection is not working with blank cells in between